# Why does this ArgMax take so long to compute?

Tags: computational-complexity

I have the following code which is supposed to return me the arguments for $l1,k1$ that maximize the function $fsub$, subject to constraints. I need the answers algebraically as functions of the other parameters (rather than numerical answers). However, it doesn't do this, and instead keeps computing for a long time.

**Why doesn't it compute this?**

```
ClearAll[fsub, l1, l2, k1, k2, k, l, e, alpha, beta, gamma, a1, a2];

alpha = beta = gamma = 1/3;
fsub[e_, l1_, l_, k1_, k_] := 
 e^(alpha)*(l1 + a1*k1)^(beta)*((l - l1) + a2*(k - k1))^gamma

fsub[e, l1, l, k1, k]

ArgMax[{fsub[e, l1, l, k1, 
   k], (l1 >= 0) \[And] (l >= l1) \[And] (k1 >= 0) \[And] (k >= 
     k1)}, {l1, k1}]
```

Comment: The parameters a1,a2 aren't defined...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, Isn't it possible to receive an answer that depends on those parameters? I intentionally did not define them, because I want the solution as a function of $a1, a2$.

Comment: Yes it's possible. You have to define a function around ArgMax[] with parameters `...[a1_?NumericQ,a2_?NumericQ]` as arguments. Also your functioncall fsub must include these two parameters.